# Showing object axis in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, axis

I'm trying to follow along with a YouTube video that deals with axis in Blender.

The author in the video uses Blender 2.6, while I'm using Blender 2.8.

In Blender 2.8, I would like to show the object's axis. I have drawn a green arrow towards it:

[image]

However, I don't see such an object on the axis.

How could I show it?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. You can select the 'Move' tool in the toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>> <kbd>G</kbd>:

[image]

2. If you would like the gizmo to appear regardless of the tool you have selected, click the '*Viewport Gizmos*' button in the *3D View* header, enable gizmos for active object by enabling the 'Active Object' option and then enable the 'Move', 'Rotate' or 'Scale' options:

[image]

Note: Both these options require the object to be selected for the gizmo to appear. If no gizmos are appearing, make sure gizmos are enabled by clicking the '*Show Gizmos*' button:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is also an 'Axis' option in the Object Properties tab > Viewport Display panel.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here to learn how to show the XYZ axis & floor for the *entire viewport* do this:

[image: select floor and xyz]

- Select the two overlapping spheres icon (the overlay menu).
- Check the 'Floor' checkbox and click on the 'X', 'Y' and 'Z' toggles.